# Returning an object to a method

Tags: java

How can I call call the retriveRoom method and return the rooms[connectedRoom] object, and use the objects properties inside of the method in the ROOMS CLASS? Any help is greatly appreciated. It is saying it cannot find the room.numLights in the system.out.println???

```
 //MASTERCONTROLPANEL CLASS

 public static Object retrieveRoom(int connectedRoom){
    connectedRoom -= 1;
    return rooms[connectedRoom];
    }


 //ROOMS CLASS
 public void roomHeatLoss(){
    //I am having problems with the line below//
    ***Object room***= MasterControlPanel.retrieveRoom(1);
     System.out.println("" + room.numLights);
}
```

Comment: Your syntax looks fine (without the stars, of course). What exactly is your problem here?

Comment: i am getting the error saying it cannot find room.numLights, I need to be able to access the objects properties??

Comment: Ah, now with the edit it is more clear. Please also add the error message to the question.

Comment: And please amend your title accordingly. You have already received the returned object before the compilation error so there is obviously no problem with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the method to return a Room or casting the Object prior to invoking the method.

Either this:

```
public static Room retrieveRoom(int connectedRoom){
   return rooms[connectedRoom];
}
```

or this:

```
public void roomHeatLoss(){
    Room room = (Room)MasterControlPanel.retrieveRoom(1);
}
```

You don't say what your problem is.  That would help us to figure out what to suggest.

Comment: I tried doing this but I am getting the errors saying "cannot find symbol" for the Room room = (room) part

Comment: @user969729: CaPiTaLiZaTiOn matters! `(room) != (Room)`

Comment: I don't know if Room is a type of yours; I guessed because you provided no other information.  If you don't have a Room class or interface, disregard my guess - and give us more information about what the type ought to be.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply declare the method to return a Room, not an Object?

```
 // public static Object retrieveRoom(int connectedRoom){
 public static Room retrieveRoom(int connectedRoom){
   connectedRoom -= 1;
   return rooms[connectedRoom];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not getting your problem
which is the ROOM Class. {Please give the detailed information}
Any ways
convert the retrieved object to Room class.